# Can't scroll PageView in flutter when run on browser

Tags: flutter-pageview

I was following Mitch Koko's tutorial about cloning TikTok UI using flutter. At some point he used PageView so user can scroll up or down. His app was working fine and so was mine. But I can't scroll when the code is deployed on Crome or Edge browser.
I used stateless widget and it works fine on emulator. Later tried a simple app with a PageView and the problem was still persistent.
[ The tutorial used stateless widget too. Mitch also showed browser version and scroll was working in his laptop ]
Any idea or thought?